# Какие глаголы-связки возможны перед кратким прилагательным

Tags: глаголы, сказуемые, краткое-причастие, краткое-прилагательное

Я насчитал всего 3 глагола.

> Он остался/оказался жив.
> Он был/есть/будет жив.

Сомнительно:

> Он стал мертв.
> Он стал бодр.
> Он стал силён.

Отмечу что конструкции типа

> Он кажется бодр.

Подразумевают нулевую связку **есть**, которая уже есть в моём списке.

Где посмотреть список таких глаголов-связок?

Comment: **Он кажется бодр** — думаю, неверно. Считаю, что правильно так: "Он, кажется, бодр" или "Он кажется бодрым".

Comment: да, ваша правда ... недосмотрел: Он, мне кажется, бодр